# how can i use sequelize.fn('ifnull') on two columns from different tables

Tags: sequelize.js

here is the sql:

```
SELECT IFNULL(A.price, B.price)
FROM table1 B
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT price
        ,product_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE user_id = xxx
    ) A
    ON A.product_id = B.product_id
```

how can I get the same results with sequelize.findAll()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have associations defined from A to B

```
Model.A.findAll({where:{user_id:XXX}, include:Model.B})
```

If you don't have associations, You can use [raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html).

```
sequelize.query('SELECT IFNULL(A.price, B.price) FROM table1 B INNER JOIN (SELECT price, product_id FROM table2 WHERE user_id=:uid) A ON A.product_id=B.product_id',{replacements:{uid:xxx}})
```